# How do I Store 2 8bit Register data into 1 16bit varrible?

Tags: c, embedded

I am looking at taking the 10 bit data from my ADC conversion and storing it into 1 16 bit integer data looks like 0x03 ADRESH 0xFF ADRESL. What I am doing right now is

```
    data = 0x03 & ADRESH;
    data = data << 8;
    data = data & 0x03FF & ADRESL;
```

will this work how I think it should or am I missing something? thanks for the help

Comment: Does your plattform use little-endian or big-endian? (In case it matters for your use case?)

Comment: it doesn't really matter I need ADRESH in the top 8 bits and ADRESL in the low 8 bits, or msb xxxxxx11 11111111 lsb

Comment: Your third statement is wrong. Thomaz Ruiz' answer is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the `|` operator ? `short data = ((0x03 & ADRESH) << 8) | ADRESL;` should work fine.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my C I wanted to make sure that I don't lose the data so that is the reason I use the mask. I am afraid that the shift will clear the data as each register is only 8 bits wide

Comment: You may be right, depending of the optimizations your compiler use. To make sure the data is not lost, you can add a cast on the first operation : `(short)(0x03 & ADRESH)`.

Comment: For the integer promotion rules of C the operands of the '&' will be promoted to "int"s (signed; 0x03 is already an "int"), so the short will get the intended result. However as Thomas Ruiz mentioned, casting makes the intention clearer (and will also help in some cases if the compiler does not fully conform the standard - I had seen examples of this).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work

```
data = data & 0x03FF & ADRESL;
```

Should be closer to

```
data = data | ADRESL;
or 
data |= ADRESL;
```

It is good that you performed the 8 byte shift in your 16-bit `data`.

Note: the `& 0x03FF` is not needed.
Note: Insure the data type of `data` is at least 16 bits.
Note: If you continue to have issues, insure the 10 bit alignment is as you think.  Many A/D modules allow the 10-bit data to be in the upper 10 bits rather than the lower.